# How to copy characters in an empty string in C?

Tags: c

I have some strings that look like `<12>`, where the numbers range from 1 to 100. Now I want to extract the numbers from the string, i.e. drop the brackets.

This is what I wrote:

```
char str[5] = "<12>";
char final[5] = "";
for(int i=0;i<strlen(str);i++){
    if(isdigit(str[i])){
        final[i] = str[i];
    }
}
```

However, I wasn't able to copy the desired number into this empty string and I got nothing printed out. What's the problem?

Comment: Think about what character will be in `final[0]`

Comment: With a reputation of 336, I am surprised that you are not debugging your code.

Comment: Consider using sscanf. This example will take at most 3 numbers between `'<'` and `'>'` characters - `sscanf(str, "<%3[0-9]>", final);`

Answer (score 3):

The problem was on the counter you need an extra counter to add on the end of your array, and you also need add '\0' character. This is just an example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
  char str[5] = "<12>";
  char final[5] = "";
  int x=0;
  for(int i=0;i<strlen(str);i++){
    if(isdigit(str[i])){
      final[x] = str[i]; //here i have changed final counter
      x++;   
    }
  }
  final[x]='\0';

  printf("%s\n", final);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: extremely inefficient

Comment: @P__J__ nobody talk about efficience here, obviously there are libraries to do this, but I guess that he is learning C. I only tried to answer the question.

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<strlen(str);i++){` -- You would have your head handed to you if you wrote that for a reputable software firm.

Comment: At issue is that `strlen(str)` is called `strlen(str)+1` times, so what should be an O(N) algorithm is taking O(N^2) time. `strlen` doesn't need to be called at all! Simple fix: `for(int i=0; str[i]; i++)`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the fact that you're using the same counter to parse your string and add elements to your new string.

Because of that, the first character you're adding to final is added to the position [1] (the first character that is a digit) instead of being added to position [0]

Answer (score -1):

https://godbolt.org/z/n8bRxW

```
char *copyDigitsOnly(char *dest, const char *src)
{
    char *tmp = dest;
    if(src && dest)
    {
        while(*src)
        {
            if(isdigit(*src))
            {
                *tmp++ = *src;
            }
            src++;
        }
        *tmp = 0;
    }
    return dest;
}

int main()
{
    char dest[25];
    char *src = "<34>";

    printf("%s\n", copyDigitsOnly(dest,src));
}
```

Comment: DV? Any explanation

Comment: Even two DVs! more interesting. What is wrong my friends?

Comment: Not my DV, but maybe because of the missing `const` for `src`?

Comment: @alain where - if in the main it is const by default as it string literal.

Comment: shouldn't it be `const char *src = ".."` in `main()` ?

Comment: Probably the lack of explanation of what is wrong with the OP.

Comment: @ikegami That would be my guess too. Code only answers are usually not very useful, and they certainly are not in this case. Anyone who wonders how to do this would gain zero from just getting the code.

Answer (score -3):

I think strtok might be what you are looking for: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strtok-strtok_r-functions-c-examples/

You can create an array of delim characters (in this case '<' and '>'), and parse the number into a new string that way.

Comment: definitelly not